# `echo ::memstat | mdb -k` very slow on certain machines

Tags: monitoring, solaris

As stated in the title, when I run `echo ::memstat | mdb -k` on certain machines, it is very slow. My munin graphs show a vastly increased CPU load when I run this regularly. I intend to use `::memstat` as input for munin graphs, so it needs to be run frequently.

While the process is running, I see this in the `prstat` output:

```
   PID USERNAME  SIZE   RSS STATE  PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/NLWP       
  6865 root       14M   12M cpu2     0    0   0:00:26  23% mdb/1
  6868 root       14M   12M cpu1     0    0   0:00:26  23% mdb/1
```

As you can see, it has already been running for 26 seconds. Monitoring `prstat` shows an ever increasing CPU usage during the processes run-time. It needs around 30 seconds to finish.

On another machine (granted, in terms of hardware it's beefier), it runs *much* faster. The point is, that it runs much faster as I would expect from comparing the hardware specs (8GB vs 12GB memory, 8 Cores vs 4 Cores, `SunOS 5.10 Generic_147441-01 i86pc i386 i86pc` vs `SunOS 5.10 Generic_127128-11 i86pc i386 i86pc`). But that's not the real point. My primary problem is that `echo ::memstat | mdb -k` takes 30 seconds to complete.

Can somebody please explain what's going on here? What could explain the "slowness"?

Comment: What version of Solaris? The `::memstat` operation requires a large number of TLB shootdowns that require full inter-CPU synchronization. (See [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sistare/entry/wicked_fast_memstat) for an explanation of why and what you can do about it.)

Comment: Both run SunOS 5.10 (I updated the question with `uname` details)

Comment: ... and thanks for the article... (reading it right now)...

Comment: "[These optimizations] will also be in Solaris 10 Update 8, which is patch 141444-08 for SPARC and 141445-08 for x86." ([It has since released.](https://blogs.oracle.com/patch/entry/solaris_10_8_11_update))

Comment: Hmmm... `cat /etc/release` gives me `Solaris 10 8/07` on the slow machines, and `Oracle Solaris 10 8/11` on the faster machines. So it seems that this is the problem. Could you post an answer with something like "older versions of mdb is inherently slow for `::memstat`! Upgrade!" so I can accept your answer? Credit where credit is due ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of Solaris have a much slower `::memstat` operation, due mostly to a large number of TLB shootdowns required. (And the fact that nobody had yet bothered to profile and optimize it.) Newer versions (Solaris 10 Update 8) have an optimized version. See the comments.